# Select only 1 item from Listview

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, listview

I have some code that reads the value of a Listview on a button click. However, what it does is select all the entries to add to another Listview. How do I adjust my code to allow for single items selection. Thanks

```
lvSelectRequestItems.Items.Clear()

        While dr.Read()

            Dim LVS As New ListViewItem
            'LVS.SubItems.Clear()
            With (LVS)

                .UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
                .Text = dr("Box").ToString()
                .SubItems.Add(dr("CustRef").ToString())


            End With

            lvSelectedItems.Items.Add(LVS)

        End While
```

Comment: is it web or windows?

Comment: you add LVS to the selected items collection **in the loop** so of course all the LVIs you add are in the selected items collection. if there are multiples being read from `dr` which one do you want selected?

Comment: @Plutonix whichever one the user selects. Thanks

Comment: `thelistview.MultiSelect = False`

Comment: Bjorn Multiselect is false. Thanks

Comment: then dont add the items to the selecteditems collection in code, let the user do it?  If you are trying to pick up the selection from elsewhere, then save the Item text in a variable, then find that item and add just it to the selected collection.  Very hard to tell what your code is doing - `lvSelectedRequest` is not the SOURCE used for `lvSelectedItems`.  you could just move the LVI from one LV to another

Comment: @Plutonix this seems to work: For Each item As ListViewItem In Me.lvSelectRequestItems.SelectedItems
            item.Remove()
            Me.lvSelectedItems.Items.Add(item)
        Next

Answer (score 0):

```
If ListViewObj.SelectedItems.Count >= 1 Then
    While ListViewObj.SelectedItems.Count >= 1
       ListViewObj.SelectedItems(0).Selected = False
    End While
    ListViewObj.Items(ListViewObj.FocusedItem.Index).Selected = True
End If
```

Comment: It is good to explain what your code is doing and why it resolves the OP's issue.